# C Prog fprintf not generating output

Tags: c

I've written the following code below and ran it without errors on both xcode and vscode. However, I wasn't able to get any output filename.txt. It wasn't in any of my folders.

Appreciate if anyone could help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    

    FILE *fp=NULL;
    fp = fopen("filename.txt","w+");

    if (fp!= NULL){
    fprintf(fp,"%s %d","Hello",555);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add an error message: `if( fp != NULL ){ ... } else { perror("filename.txt"); }`. Don't close the file in the error case.  (It would be more typical to write `if( fp == NULL ){ perror("filename.txt"); exit(1); }`

Comment: Assuming the `fopen` did not fail, the name should be created in the directory from which the program runs.  You could get the working directory with `getcwd` and print it to see the location.

Comment: i'm new to c programming. Can i ask how do i print getcwd? Thanks once again. I've also tried the perror method and it shows filename.txt: Permission denied. That's so strange.

Comment: If your code runs, but does not work, there is an error. Check what error!

Comment: `char name[PATH_MAX]; getcwd(name, sizeof name); printf("cwd = %s\n", name);`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, `getcwd()` is a POSIX function (in `<unistd.h>`), but we don't know what platform Terry is using, so it might not be available.  I don't think there's a Standard C function for this (given that Standard C doesn't have any concept of "directory", that shouldn't be a surprise).

Comment: "Ran without errors" doesn't mean much when you always return `0`!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Beware that `PATH_MAX` is not required to be defined. The only correct way to use `gtetcwd` is by dynamically allocating the buffer. Although it's not in POSIX, on every system I know of (even Windows), `getcwd` will do this for you if you call it with a NULL pointer and specify the size of the buffer as zero, like this: `char *cwd = getcwd(NULL, 0);`

Answer (score 4):

> ran it without errors

`fclose(NULL)` is undefined behavior (UB), so it is not clear that there was no error when file failed to open.

Print something in both cases of opening success/failure - and with a `'\n'`.  Useful to add error info.

Robust code checks all I/O operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    
  const char *filename = "filename.txt";
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"w+");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open <%s>\n", filename);
    perror("fopen()");
  } else { 
    printf("Success opening <%s>\n", filename);
    if (fprintf(fp,"%s %d","Hello", 555) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Print failure with <%s>\n", filename);
      perror("fprintf()");
    }
    if (fclose(fp) == EOF) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close <%s>\n", filename);
      perror("fclose()");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

> I've also tried the perror method and it shows filename.txt: Permission denied. [Later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74421178/c-prog-fprintf-not-generating-output/74421279#comment131377484_74421178).

Check if filename.txt is read-only, or in use by another application (editor?), or other permission limitations.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to encourage people to forget about resources that a program may hold but open files are actually among those that are released upon a regular program exit (in a hosted environment).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes: "If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination. Other paths to program termination, such as calling the abort function, need not close all files properly."  C17dr § 7.21.3 5

Answer (score 1):

If the file wasn't successfully opened, then the code does nothing (apart from closing a null `FILE`-pointer, which is undefined).  You should use `perror()` to indicate why it couldn't be opened:

```
    const char *const filename = "filename.txt";
    FILE *const fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (!fp) {
        perror(filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%s %d", "Hello", 555);
```

There's a good chance that you have an existing `filename.txt` that isn't writable by you, or you are in a directory where you can't create a new file, but we'll need the error message to actually determine why it wasn't opened.

---

Alternatively, you're running in a different working directory to where you thought you were - that's something you should investigate (perhaps produce some logging to stderr to indicate *where* the file is being created).

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it works just fine[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUD1t.png)

but, how are you compiling it and did you remember to run the a.out/execution?

Comment: I realised i get an error if i were to use fp = fopen("filename.txt","w+");  but if i change it to reflect  fp = fopen("filename","w+");, it is able to generate a file. Somehow that suffix of ".txt" is giving me some issues.